# Integrating $\dfrac{1}{(1+2x)(2\sqrt{x})}$.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to integrate the following:

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(1+2x)} $

After a series of $u$ & $s$ substitutions, I end up with the following:

$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \arctan(s) $ with upper bound $\infty$ and lower bound 0.

After evaluating with limits, I end up with the following:

$ \frac{π}{2\sqrt{2}} $

However, through experimentation the limit appears to be 63.64, which is not equal to the above.

Comment: I get what you get.  What sort of experimentation are you doing?

Comment: Try using partial fraction decomposition. I think it should work.

Comment: @joejacobz: how exactly would that work?  I think the OP has it right to begin with.

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$ is the right answer. Your experimentation must be doing something not right.

Comment: @RonGordon It would separate the integral into two different integrals that add to the original fraction. This is unnecessary now because I didn't realize OP got it right in the beginning. I didn't actually try to solve the problem.

Comment: @joejacobz: I am plenty familiar with partial fractions.  The problem here is that you have a square root and a linear function in the denominator. How would you break them apart?  You'll find that it doesn't work so well.

Comment: @Ron   Set $u^2=x$ and you've got a typical partial fraction problem, that actually simplifies to a very simple form...

Comment: I put the function into my calculator and then manually inputted values of X. As X got really big, the function had a limit of 63.64. Does anyone have some insight on properly verifying the above answer through experimentation?

Comment: @User58220: wrong.  That substitution leads to $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{du}{1+2 u^2}$$ which leads precisely to the answer via a trig substituiton.